# Can cookies be sent on along with a HTTP 30x response?

Tags: http, cookies

I have a PHP login page with the following structure:

```
<?php
    // validate login
    // ...
    if (login_okay) {
        // save user and password as secure cookies cookies
        $time = time() + 3600;
        setcookie('user', $user, $time, null, null, true);
        setcookie('pass', $pass, $time, null, null, true);

        // redirect to main page
        header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
        header('Location: /mainpage');
    }
?>
<html>
<!-- ... -->
```

However, the next time I attempt to log in, the stored user ID and password are not displayed in the form. Why is that happening? Maybe cookies cannot sent along with an HTTP 30x response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are allowed with 302 and this is a very common practice.  There is likely something wrong with the code (which you didn't include here) for later reading from the cookies and displaying their values in the form.